# Is the CIL optimized? Or only the JITted binary?

Tags: .net, optimization, compiler-construction, jit, cil

I was wondering, when compilers output to [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language), is the CIL optimized? Assuming the language doesn't insert bonus data information in debug mode i was wondering if the JIT does all optimizations completely by itself and i assume it could.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both. If you build in release mode, whichever compiler you're using will apply some optimization to the code before it goes into CIL. The JITter has optimizations too.

An example of an optimization typically done by the compiler is constant folding.

An example of an optimization typically done at JIT level is loop unrolling.

Comment: this seems wrong. What would the compiler do that the JITer couldnt? could you give me an example of a compiler optimization

Comment: @acidzombie24: Just because the JITter can do something does not mean it has to. Some optimizations a JITter simply will not attempt, simply because the JIT needs to be extremely fast so as to not interrupt the user. An example of an optimization typically done inside the front end rather than by the JITter is constant folding.

Comment: @acidzombie24, why should the JITter do all the work? The compiler can remove unused method calls, inline code, etc.

Comment: @bzlm: I'm not sure if the compiler does inlining -- I know the JITter does that.

Comment: @Billy, I have no idea. I'd imagine it varies with implementation and compiler. My point was it can. :)

Comment: @bzlm: well... if theres an unused method i'd imagine it wouldn't **need** to be removed as it is never called. There is F#, C#, VB.NET, ironpython, nemerle, boo and probably other .NET languages i never heard of. Theres at least 4 ms maintains (C++CLR being another). I was wondering if they designed it so the languages dont need to optimize anything. I am pretty sure theres no 'const folding' as const variables (maybe i remember it wrong) have address and reference in another binary so it cant be inline while enums dont use variables but pulled values as i dont think they would store names

Comment: @acidzombie: Constant folding has nothing to do with `const` variables. Constant folding is replacing `2+2` with the precomputed value `4` in the binary.